the density of $C(\Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ in $L^2(\Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$
Let $\Gamma$ is a cocompact group of SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$), which acts discontinously on SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$), then SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$)/$\Gamma$ has finite volume(of course their is an invarant measure on it, which is induced by the Haar measure on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma$ by quoitent formula), here we assume $-I\in \Gamma$. Let $\chi$ be a unitary character of $\Gamma$, define $C(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ be the space of all continous function $f$ on SL($2,\mathbb{R}$) such that for every $\gamma\in \Gamma, f(\gamma g)=\chi(\gamma)f(g)$, and define $L^2(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ be the measureable function on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ which satisfy the same condition above, but with an additional preperty that
$\int_{\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|f(x)|^2dx<+\infty$ (mention that $|f|$ is an well defined function on $\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$)
Prove: $C(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ is dense in $L^2(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$
It seems like a well know fact that on any locally compact hausdroff space $X$, $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$, and if $\chi=1$, it can easily deduce what I want to prove. But if it is not the case, then I can not make a function $f$ in $C(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ into a function $\tilde{f}\in C(\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma)$ since there is no canioncal way to choose a 'fundamental domain'. Maybe other ways are more helpful, such as use a function $g$ only in $C_c(\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}))$ to approach $f\in L^2(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi) $, and convolution $g$ with a suitable function in $C(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$, but I have difficulty to do it.
The topology of $L^2(\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$ is induced by the distance defined by $\int_{\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx$, here mention again that at that time $|f-g|$ is a well defined function on $\Gamma \backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$

Your question seems to be incomplete. Please post the full question. (BTW, $\chi$ is \chi, and LaTeX (Mathjax) formulae should be enclosed in pairs of $ $).

@Steve sorry, I'm not familiar enough using mse.

Your definition of $L^2$ is wrong, it should be the integral of $f^2$, not of $|f|$. Also, I assume, you are using the projection of the Haar measure on $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ to define $dx$, right? Also, the topology on $L^2$ presumably is given by the Hilbert space norm, right? Also, cocompact implies finite volume of the quotient.

@Moishe Yes, you're right. I corrected the error of the definition of $L^2$
, and add the things you said to make the problem more clear.

OK, better now. But you do not need absolute values since you square your functions. In any case, are you familiar with vector bundles? These provide the right formalism for proving such results (using a partition of unity).

@Moishe the function I considered are complex so I think absolute value is needed. I know the definition of vector bundles and some basic properties, but I don’t know how to combine my question with it, can you explain it for me more clearly?

I see: This was not immediately clear to me from the text. I will write a proper answer later, when I have more time. The trick is to define a complex line bundle over $B=\Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb R)$ associated with the character $\chi$, so that your functions are effectively sections of this line bundle. Then one uses a partition of unity on the base $B$ corresponding to a local trivialization of the line bundle.

Let’s move the discussion to chat.

OK, maybe I have found how to solve this. Convolution is enough. First for any function $g\in L^2(\Gamma\backslash\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\chi)$, choose a function $\phi$, and consider $g * \phi$ which difined as $g* \phi(x)=\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}g(xh^{-1})\phi(h)dh=\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}g(h)\phi(h^{-1}x)dh$
immediately we can find $g* \phi(\gamma x)=\chi(\gamma)(g*\phi)(x),\forall \gamma\in\Gamma$, and what we need to prove is it is continous and can be close to $g$ arbitrarily.
first, since $|(g*\phi)(y)-(g*\phi)(x))|\leq \int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|g(yh^{-1})-g(xh^{-1})||\phi(h)| dh\leq C\int_U|g(yh^{-1})-g(xh^{-1})|dh$
there $C=\sup \phi$, so we should assume $\phi$ compact support and continous, $U$ contains its support and small enough so that the restriction of the projection from $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma $ on $\bar{U}$ is injective, thus differmorphism on $U$,  so we know $U$ has finite measure($\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$ have). And we have
$|\int_U|g(yh^{-1})-g(xh^{-1})|dh|^2=|\int_U|g(tx)-g(x)|dx|^2\leq \int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma}|g(tx)-g(x)|^2dx \text{vol}(U)$
where $t=yx^{-1}$, and since $|g|\in L^2({\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma})$, we know the right side can be small enough if $t$ is near $e$(approaching $g(x)$ with a function in $C_c({\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma})$ and it can be easily deduced since its of course right for the function in $C_c(X)$)
Second, we should make $g*\phi$ and $g$ close enough, we should assume $\phi$ has integral $1$ on ${\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}$.
then
$|g*\phi(x)-g(x)|^2\leq  |\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)||\phi(h)|dh|^2\leq (\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2|\phi(h)|dh)(\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|\phi(h)|dh)$
the last step is Cauchy inequality, the second factor of the right side is $1$, and the first factor is $\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})}|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2|\phi(h)|dh=\int_U|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2|\phi(h)|dh$
and the distance of $g*\phi $ and $g$ is
$\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma}|g*\phi(x)-g(x)|^2 dx\leq \int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma}\int_U|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2|{\phi}(h)|dhdx$
$=\int_U|{\phi}(h)|\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma}|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2dxdh$
as above, if $U$ is a neibourhood of $e$ and small enough, we can make sure $\int_{\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma}|g(xh^{-1})-g(x)|^2dx<\epsilon$, so the distance is small enough
And we conclude that the $\phi$ we choose should be a continous function on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and has compact support in $U$, where $\bar{U}$ is small enough so that its projection on $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$ is differmorphism, and $\phi$ has integral $1$ on $U$. This completes the proof.
